# Explanation of proof derivative of logarithms

Tags: logarithms, proof-explanation

Why does the proof of the derivative of $log_a(x)$ involve natural logarithms like $ln$? Couldn't creators of the proof used non-natural logarithms like $log$ instead? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Because they are *natural*. The definition of the natural logarithm and exponential varies, but it must always be tied to $\ln$. If you provide your definition for these functions, we can explain more clearly.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah what is meant by exponential?

Comment: Just to clarify what Jeffery Opoku-Mensah said, $e^x$ is the unique exponential function which is equal to its own derivative.  All other exponentials have extra factors in their derivatives.  So $e$ is natural because its easier.  Same for $ln$.  That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but consider this

$$
\frac{\log_a(x + h) -\log_a(x)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}\log_a\left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right) = \log_a\left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h}
$$

In the limit when $h$ goes to $0$ you have

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\log_ax = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log_a(x + h) -\log_a(x)}{h} = \log_a \lim_{h\to 0}\left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h} = \log_a e^{1/x}
$$

The problem is now how to evaluate this last expression, let us call

$$
y = \log_a e^{1/x}
$$

This is equivalent to

$$
a^y = e^{1/x}
$$

You know that the inverse of $e$ is $\ln$, so

$$
\ln a^y = \frac{1}{x}
$$

or equivalently

$$
y = \frac{1}{x \ln a} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\log_ax
$$

The appearance of the natural logarithm in this expression is the a natural consequence (pun not intended) of $e$ showing up in the limit. Note that at no point a relation between $\log_a$ and $\ln$ was assumed.

Comment: With this why is the first line not `\frac{1}{h}log_a\left(\frac{xh]{x}\right)`?

Comment: @Jinzu $\log_a(xh) \not= \log_a(x + h)$

Comment: could you explain where the log_a(1) comes from?

Comment: @Jinzu Sure, which line do you mean?

Comment: the first line and the second

Comment: @Jinzu I see, there's a typo in the answer, 

$$
\frac{1}{h}(\log_a(x + h) - \log_a(x)) = \frac{1}{h}\log_a((x + h) / x) = \frac{1}{a}\log_a(1 + h/x) = \log_a(1 + h/x)^{1/h}
$$